# Calculate probability/ percentage

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

a consumer advocacy group tested the "on- air" lifetime of a random study sample of 162 batteries . the mean lifetime was 2.9 hours with a standard deviation of 0.4 hours. estimate the percentage of batteries with lifetimes between 2.1 and 3.7 hours.

The answer is 100% ~ 1 probability ??

Comment: Assume the distribution of survival time is normal. What is the probabily of the time of survival of a given colony to be less than two standard errors away from the mean value ?

Comment: Just take `normcdf(([2.1 3.7]-2.9)/0.4)`

Comment: @hyprfrco , oh we use standard deviation just 0.4 or we need to use. 0.4/√162 ?

Comment: @Evargalo , oh so its 95% ?

Comment: With the approximation $1.96\approx 2$, yes... Totally different question, may I deduce from your pseudo that you are a chess player ?

Comment: @Evargalo . yes I am chess player. , so sir 95% is correct answer?

Comment: I think yes. At least $95\%$ is an estimate of the percentage of batteries with lifetimes between 2.116 and 3.684 hours.

Comment: @Evargalo, thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that P(2.1 < x < 3.7) can be written as P(x=3.7) - P(x=2.1). Recall that the equation for a z-score given information about a single sample is:

z = (x – x̄) / s

Since we are given that the distribution is normal and that our sample mean is 2.9 hours we let our x̄ = 2.9 hours. Since our sample standard deviation is given we can let s = .4 With this information we can find the probabilities corresponding to the respective z-score values of P(x=3.7), P(x=2.1)

Comment: so we use simple s , no need s/√n ?

Comment: I also wanted to mention, as some comments already have, you can check to make sure that your answer makes sense by thinking about the Empirical Rule.

Comment: Yes, if we had been given the population standard deviation we would want that (σ / √n), (Which is the standard deviation the sample of a normal distribution)BUT we are given the sample's standard deviation so there is no need to make that substitution